# Extract memoized results in the form of a rule

Tags: variable-definitions, memoization

Lets say I define a function `f` with memoization. Is there some way to extract the memoized values?

For example,

```
f[0] = 1; f[1] = 5; f[20] = 42
```

Is there some way to get a list similar to `{0 -> 1, 1 -> 5, 20 -> 42}`?

Note, `FullDefinition` is close, but I dont know how to handle its output.

Comment: You may want to start by taking a look at the docs for `DownValues[]`

Comment: Ah, yes, of course! I feel silly now.

Answer (score 4):

This will work more generally for memoized functions taking one integer argument.

```
Clear[f];
f[0] = 1;
f[x_Integer] := f[x] = f[x - 1] + 1/x
f /@ Range[3];
Cases[DownValues[f], f[i_Integer] :> Rule[i, f[i]], Infinity]
```

> ```
> {0 -> 1, 1 -> 2, 2 -> 5/2, 3 -> 17/6}
> ```

Answer (score 1):

```
f[0] = 1; f[1] = 5; f[20] = 42;

Rule @@@
 Partition[
  Cases[DownValues[f], _Integer, Infinity],
  2]
```

> {0 -> 1, 1 -> 5, 20 -> 42}

Comment: extremely nice !

Comment: @eldo Thanks. In your approach, use Identity rather than Sequence.

Comment: I like this, but there is a problem with it. Although it works for the OP's example date, it won't work for a memoized function like `f[0] = 1; f[x_Integer] := f[x] = f[x - 1] + 1/x`.

Answer (score 1):

For this particular situation the following is an alternative and since no Pattern matching is being done here, it is slightly faster than the `Cases` solutions provided.

```
makeFRule[func_, start_, end_] := MapThread[Rule, Rest @ Extract[DownValues[func][[start ;; end]], 
{{0}, {All, 1, 1, 1}, {All, 1, 1}}]]
```

Test data:

```
lis = Transpose[{Range[10^6], RandomInteger[10, 10^6]}];
(f[#1] = #2) & @@@ lis; (* create DownValues *)
```

Timings:

```
rule1 = makeFRule[f, 1, -1]; // AbsoluteTiming
rule2 = Cases[DownValues[f], f[i_Integer] :> Rule[i, f[i]], Infinity]; // 
AbsoluteTiming
rule1 == rule2

(* 
8.852543
10.243611
True
 *)
```