# How to access all instances of a defined function

Tags: list-manipulation, variable-definitions, algorithm

This should have a simple solution, but for some reason I cannot find how to do this.

Let's say I have a "function" where I have defined values (in my actual example I have many instances of this, but here I will just show 3).

```
func[1] = 3;
func[2] = 5;
func[3] = 9;
```

I can see what all of the definitions of `func` are by just calling

```
Definition[func]
```

> func[1] = 3
>
> func[2] = 5
>
> func[3] = 9

But what if I want to explicitly access all of the definitions I have made for `func`. In other words, how can I just get a list of the "inputs" that have been defined? Something like:

> {1, 2, 3}

Comment: Maybe `(DownValues[func] /. func -> List)[[All, 1, 1]]` does what you want?

Comment: I would use `DownValues[func][[All, 1, 1, 1]]`.

Comment: @CarlWoll Think about multiple-argument definitions like `func[3, 5] = 19;`...

Comment: Maybe `ReplacePart[DownValues[func], {_, 1, 1, 0} -> List][[All, 1, 1]]` is a bit more robust. Just in case `func` appears as its own argument like in `func[func] = 0` ...

Comment: @CarlWoll That works fine :) I knew it was a simple fix. I had completely forgot about DownValues. Thank you!

Comment: Related: [(50805)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/50805/121)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
func[1] = 3;
func[2, 3] = 5;
func[3, 4, 5] = 9;
```

To get a list of all the inputs and outputs of a function you can use [`DownValues`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DownValues.html).

```
DownValues@func
```

> {HoldPattern[func[1]] :> 3, HoldPattern[func[2, 3]] :> 5, HoldPattern[func[3, 4, 5]] :> 9}

Then to get all the inputs associated with explicit definitions, first replace the `func` head with `List` (in case of multiples arguments) and you then can use [`Keys`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Keys.html)

```
(Keys@DownValues@func /. func -> List)[[;; , 1]]
```

> {{1}, {2, 3}, {3, 4, 5}}

or manually pick out the part

```
(DownValues@func /. func -> List)[[;; , 1, 1]]
```

> {{1}, {2, 3}, {3, 4, 5}}